# How to prevent my formula from incorporating blank cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For my job, I frequently have to use Microsoft Powershell to create many file folders at once. I include the code that I use in Powershell below:

`"Dog","Cat","Person","People","Sandwich","Car","Banana","Orange","Notre Dame","Computer","Coding"| %{New-Item -Name “$_” -ItemType “Directory”}`

To expedite the folder-making process, I created a workbook that allows me to copy and paste folder names into a column, and then in another column, the code above automatically generates with the folder names that I copied and pasted. Here's a screenshot of the workbook below:

[image: Screenshot of Workbook]

The code that I use in the above screenshot is below:

`=""""&A2&""""&","&""""&A3&""""&","&""""&A4&""""&","&""""&A5&""""&","&""""&A6&""""&","&""""&A7&""""&","&""""&A8&""""&","&""""&A9&""""&","&""""&A10&""""&","&""""&A11&""""&","&""""&A12&""""&","&""""&A13&""""&","&""""&A14&""""&","&""""&A15&""""&","&""""&A16&""""&","&""""&A17&""""&","&""""&A18&""""&","&""""&A19&""""&","&""""&A20&""""&","&""""&A21&""""&","&""""&A22&""""&","&""""&A23&""""&","&""""&A24&""""&","&""""&A25&""""&","&""""&A26&""""&","&""""&A27&""""&","&""""&A28&""""&","&""""&A29&""""&","&""""&A30&""""&","&""""&A31&""""&","&""""&A32&""""&","&""""&A33&""""&","&""""&A34&""""&","&""""&A35&""""&","&""""&A36&""""&","&""""&A37&""""&","&""""&A38&""""&","&""""&A39&""""&","&""""&A40&""""&","&""""&A41&""""&","&""""&A42&""""&","&""""&A43&""""&","&""""&A44&""""&","&""""&A45&""""&","&""""&A46&""""&","&""""&A47&""""&","&""""&A48&""""&","&""""&A49&""""&"| %{New-Item -Name “$_” -ItemType “Directory”}"`

Ultimately, what I want to do is modify the code so that it does not incorporate blank cells when generating the Powershell code. As you can see, the formula generates Powershell code that includes a lot of extraneous commas and quotations because it is incorporating blank cells into the formula. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to come up with a new formula that does not take blank cells into consideration, and I'm hoping one of you Excel wizards can assist me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365, you can use this formula:

`=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,""""&FILTER(A2:A49,A2:A49<>"")&"""") & "| %{New-Item -Name “$_” -ItemType “Directory”}"`

Comment: Thank you so much. I can confirm that I have Microsoft 365 for Enterprise. Is there any way to modify the code you have provided so that there are quotation marks around the prospective folder names? For instance, using the provided code, I get: Orange,Cat,Person,People,Sandwich,Car,Banana,Orange,Notre Dame,Computer,Coding| %{New-Item -Name “$_” -ItemType “Directory”}. In order for the code the execute in Powershell, quotations need to be around each of the prospective folder names. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure. I've missed it. Please see updated formula.

Comment: Thank you so much!